# What's the point of implementing a Stack using two queues?

Tags: java, stack

I have the following homework question:

> Implement the stack methods push(x) and pop() using two queues.

This seems odd to me because:

- A Stack *is* a (LIFO) queue
- I don't see why you would need two queues to implement it

I searched around:

- [GeeksForGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-stack-using-queue/)
- [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688276/implement-stack-using-two-queues)

and found a couple solutions. This is what I ended up with:

```
public class Stack<T> {
    LinkedList<T> q1 = new LinkedList<T>();
    LinkedList<T> q2 = new LinkedList<T>();

    public void push(T t) {
        q1.addFirst(t);
    }

    public T pop() {
        if (q1.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "Can't pop from an empty stack!");
        }

        while(q1.size() > 1) {
            q2.addFirst( q1.removeLast() );
        }

        T popped = q1.pop();

        LinkedList<T> tempQ = q1;
        q1 = q2;
        q2 = tempQ;

        return popped;
    }
}
```

But I don't understand what the advantage is over using a single queue; the two queue version seems pointlessly complicated.

Say we choose for pushes to be the more efficient of the 2 (as I did above), `push` would remain the same, and `pop` would simply require iterating to the last element, and returning it. In both cases, the `push` would be `O(1)`, and the `pop` would be `O(n)`; but the single queue version would be drastically simpler. It should only require a single for loop.

Am I missing something? Any insight here would be appreciated.

Comment: A queue is typically referring to a FIFO structure while the stack is a LIFO structure.  The interface for LinkedList in Java is that of a deque (double ended queue) which allows both FIFO and LIFO access.  Try changing programming to the [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface rather than the LinkedList implementation.

Comment: Yes, I realized that I'm using "illegal operations" for the question. I literally reversed every `push`/`pop` (front for back) so I'm only using legal methods, and it operates the same. I don't know if I should update the code since it's mostly besides the question.

Comment: The more usual problem is to implement a queue using two stacks. You might find Chris Okasaki's book on purely functional data structures interesting.

Comment: Building off what Eric said, you can sometimes find yourself in a stack based language (such as [dc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_(computer_program)) or a [push down automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) with two stacks (equivalent to a turing machine because, well, you can do more)) where you may find yourself with multiple stacks, but no queue.

Comment: @MichaelT: Or you can also find yourself running on a stack based CPU

Comment: *"A stack is a (LIFO) queue"*... uhm, a queue is a waiting line. Like the line for using a public restroom. Do the lines you wait in ever behave in a LIFO fashion? Stop using the term "LIFO queue", it's nonsensical.

Comment: Anyone that can write this code and answer a few questions on their code clearly understands queue and stacks, hence a very good task to help students build the understanding.

Comment: @Mehrdad, referring to a stack as a type of queue is not nonsensical, it uses the general definition given in [Queueing Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Queueing_theory) as any method used by a system with limited resources to prioritize access to those resources to elements waiting in line.

Comment: @yoniLavi: I don't disagree that it's popular nomenclature, but that doesn't imply it makes any sense. A calling a stack a "LIFO queue" makes as much sense as calling ethernet "wired Wi-Fi".

Comment: @Mehrdad That's not a correct way of thinking about it. A Priority queue is a queue and it's not FIFO (as in you bathroom example). If I implemented a stack using a priority queue where the element's order was based on insertion time, would that not be a queue?

Comment: The whole *point* of a queue is that your enqueue time should have *some vague sort of inverse correspondence* with your dequeue time. In other words, with *any* kind of queue, given no additional information, then *your best guess is that those enqueued later will be dequeued later*. Sure, it might not be 100% accurate, but "queue" still (statistically) describes the overall trend. But with a stack, which *exactly behaves in the **opposite** fashion*, this is *strictly the worst possible guess*--at that point, it bears **exactly zero** resemblance to a queue. (That's 0%! Not even 1%!)

Comment: (...cont'd) If you think about the uses of priority queues, it is *generally true* (i.e., there exists a statistical trend) that those enqueued later are still dequeued later than those enqueued earlier. For example, breadth-first-search is an approximation to Dijkstra's algorithm in many cases, even though in particular instances it might not be a great approximation. A stack is *never* ***any*** kind of approximation to a queue. It has precisely the opposite behavior in ***every*** situation, so calling it a queue is completely nonsensical.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is no advantage: this is a purely academic exercise.

A *very* long time ago when I was a freshman in college I had a similar exercise<sup>1</sup>. The goal was to teach students how to use object-oriented programming to implement algorithms instead of writing iterative solutions using `for` loops with loop counters. Instead, combine and reuse existing data structures to achieve your goals.

You will never use this code in the Real World<sup>TM</sup>. What you need to take away from this exercise is how to "think outside the box" and reuse code.

---

Please note that you *should* be using the [java.util.Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface in your code instead of using the implementation directly:

```
Queue<T> q1 = new LinkedList<T>();
Queue<T> q2 = new LinkedList<T>();
```

This allows you to use other `Queue` implementations if desired, as well as hiding<sup>2</sup> methods that are on `LinkedList` that might get around the spirit of the `Queue` interface. This includes `get(int)` and `pop()` (while your code compiles, there is a logic error in there given the constraints of your assignment. Declaring your variables as `Queue` instead of `LinkedList` will reveal it). Related reading: [Understanding “programming to an interface”](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/232359/22815) and [Why are interfaces useful?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/108240/22815)

<sup>1</sup> <sup><sub>I still remember: the exercise was to reverse a Stack using *only* methods on the Stack interface and no utility methods in `java.util.Collections` or other "static only" utility classes. The correct solution involves using other data structures as temporary holding objects: you have to know the different data structures, their properties, and how to combine them to do it. Stumped most of my CS101 class who had never programmed before.</sub></sup>

<sup>2</sup> <sup><sub>The methods are still there, but you cannot access them without type casts or reflection. So it is not *easy* to use those non-queue methods.</sub></sup>

Comment: Thanks. I guess that makes sense. I also realized that I'm using "illegal" operations in the above code (pushing to the front of a FIFO), but I don't think that changes anything. I reversed all of the operations, and it still works as intended. I'm going to wait a bit before I accept as I don't want to discourage any other people from giving input. Thank you though.

Answer (score 21):

There is no advantage. You have correctly realized that using Queues to implement a Stack leads to horrible time complexity. No (competent) programmer would ever do something like this in “real life”.

But it's possible. You can use one abstraction to implement another, and vice versa. A Stack can be implemented in terms of two Queues, and likewise you could implement a Queue in terms of two stacks. The advantage of this *exercise* is:

- you recap Stacks
- you recap Queues
- you get accustomed to algorithmic thinking
- you learn stack-related algorithms
- you get to think about tradeoffs in algorithms
- by realizing the equivalence of Queues and Stacks, you connect various topics of your course
- you gain practical programming experience

Actually, this is a great exercise. I should do it myself right now :)

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thanks for your edit, but I really meant “horrible time complexity”. For a linked-list-based stack `push`, `peek` and `pop` operations are in O(1). The same for a resizeable array-based stack, except that `push` is in O(1) amortized, with O(n) worst case. Compared with that, a queue-based stack is vastly inferior with O(n) push, O(1) pop and peek, or alternatively O(1) push, O(n) pop and peek.

Comment: "horrible time complexity" and "vastly inferior" is not exactly right. Amortized complexity is still O(1) for push *and* pop. There's a fun question in TAOCP (vol1?) about that (basically you have to show that the number of times an element can switch from one stack to the other is constant). Worst case performance for one operation is different, but then I rarely hear anybody talking about O(N) performance for push in ArrayLists - not the *usually* interesting number.

Answer (score 6):

There is definitely a real purpose for making a queue out of two stacks.  If you use immutable data structures from a functional language, you can push into a stack of pushable items, and pull from a list of poppable items.  The poppable items gets created when all items have been popped out, and the new poppable stack is the reverse of the pushable stack, where the new pushable stack is now empty.  It's efficient.

As for a stack made of two queues?  That might make sense in a context where you have a bunch of large and fast queues available.  It's definitely useless as this sort of Java exercise.  But it might make sense if those are channels or messaging queues.  (ie: N messages enqueued, with an O(1) operation to move (N-1) items at the front into a new queue.)

Comment: Hmm.. this made me think about using shift registers as the basis of computing and about the belt/mill architecture

Comment: wow, the Mill CPU is indeed interesting.  A "Queue Machine" for sure.

Answer (score 3):

The exercise *is* needlessly contrived from a practical standpoint. The point is to force you to use the interface of the queue in a clever way to implement the stack. For example, your "One queue" solution requires that you iterate over the queue to get the last input value for stack "pop" operation. However, a queue data structure does not allow to iterate over the values, you are restricted to access them in the first-in, first-out (FIFO).

Answer (score 3):

As others already noted: there is no real-world advantage.

Anyway, one answer to the second part of your question, why not simply to use one queue, is beyond the Java.

In Java even the `Queue` interface has a `size()` method and all the standard implementations of that method are O(1).

That is not necessarily true for the naive/canonical linked list as a C/C++ programmer would implement, which would just keep pointers to the first and last element and each element a pointer to the next element.

In that case `size()` is O(n) and should be avoided in loops. Or the implementation is opaque and only provides the bare minimum `add()` and `remove()`.

With such an implementation you'd have to count the number of elements first by transfering them into the second queue, transfer `n-1` elements back to the first queue and return the remaining element.

That said, it would probably not make up something like this if you live in Java-land.

Comment: Good point about the `size()` method. However, in the absence of an O(1) `size()` method, it's trivial for the stack to keep track of its current size itself. Nothing to stop a one-queue implementation.

Comment: It all depends on the implementation. If you have a queue, implemented with only forward pointers and pointers to first and last element, you could still write and algorithm which removes an element, saves it to a local variable, adds the element previously in that variable to the same queue until the first element is seen again. This only works if you can uniquely identify an element (e.g. via pointer) and not just something with the same value. O(n) and only uses add() and remove(). Anyway, it is easier to optimize, that to find a reason to actually do that, except thinking about algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to imagine a use for such an implementation, it's true. But **most of the point is to prove that it can be done**.

In terms of actual uses for these things, however, I can think of two. **One use for this is implementing systems in constrained environments that weren't designed for it**: for example, [Minecraft's redstone blocks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20219/is-minecraft-turing-complete) turn out to represent a Turing-complete system, which people have used to implement logic circuits and even entire CPUs. In the earliest days of script-driven gaming, many of the first game bots were also implemented this way.

But **you can also apply this principle in reverse, ensuring that something *isn't* possible in a system when you don't want it to be**. This can come up in security contexts: for example, powerful configuration systems can be an asset, but there are still degrees of power that you might rather not give to users. This constrains what you can allow the configuration language to do, lest it be subverted by an attacker, but in this case, that's what you want.